# How to make reuseable blocks of HTML based upon a model object

Tags: django, django-templates

Say I have a simple model with Title, Price, Description and Image fields. I would like 3 html outputs/blocks that I can reuse for each object of this model. For added 'complexity', 2 of the outputs will be combined to make the 3rd. So, here is what these 3 output might look like in a template.

output_image

```
<span class="output_image"><img src="{{ object.image.url }}" alt="{{ object.title}}></span>
```

output_info

```
<ul class="output_info">
    <li>{{ object.title }}</li>
    <li>Price: {{ object.price }}</li>
    <li>{{ object.description }}</li>
</ul>
```

output_all (wraps up the previous 2)

```
<div class="output_all">
    <span class="output_image">...</span>
    <ul class="output_info">...</ul>
</div>
```

I might want to use output_image on a search page, and output_all on listing and advanced search, for example. Hence I only want to write this output once, and reuse it. What is the best way to achieve this?

Initially I thought to add methods/properties to the model class, which would return the formatted html. This worked, and in my template I could just call `{{ object.output_all  }}`, for example. Is it bad practice to output html like this?

I have briefly looked at other ways too. Inclusion tags seems to work, but I have only tested with a 'complete' version of the output_all case (ie have not 'nested' the other 2 output tags within output_all yet). Is this the correct method, and is it possible to 'nest' the tags?

Comment: If I have understood your question, I think this can help you: https://github.com/clintecker/django-chunks

Comment: Close, but that seems to be for static content. I need dynamically created content based upon the object selected.

Answer (score 0):

I would use inclusion tags for this. Keep presentation logic where it belongs, in templates.

Comment: Yes, I think you are correct. But there seems to be a 'disconnect', as inclusion tags are created in their own file, with no 'tie' to the model. I could potentially pass the wrong object to a tag. IMO, it would be more logical to specify an inclusion tag for a model in the models file, which is linked to a html template. Thus, instead of `{% special_tag object %}`, you could do `{{ object.special_tag }}`, and this would prevent `{% special_tag wrong_object %}` (yes I know you don't pass the object like that, but use takes_context, I am just demonstrating). I believe this isn't possible though?